# Prove $C_c(R^n)$ is dense in $C_0(R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $C_c$ is dense in $C_0$ if $\forall g \in C_0 $exists a sequence $\{g_n\}\in C_c : g_n \rightarrow$g w.r.t $||.||_{\infty}$.

But I have no idea how proof this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $0\leq\phi_n\leq1$ be a continuous function satisfying $\phi_n(x)=1$ for $|x|\leq n$ an $\phi_n(x)=0$ for $|x|>n+1$. Take $g\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^m)$, and approximate it by $g_n=\phi_ng\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^m)$. I leave it to you to show that the error
$$
\|g-g_n\|_\infty
=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^m}|g(x)-\phi_n(x)g(x)|
=
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^m}|1-\phi_n(x)|\cdot|g(x)|,
$$
goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Why the sup goes to zero?

Comment: In your first sentence you need $\phi_n$ all the way through. More importantly, there are no such functions. Also $n$ has a given meaning in this problem, so it should be $\phi_m$ or something..

Comment: Typo in the answer: I imagine that you intend $\varphi$ to be $1$ inside $[-n,n]$ and $0$ outside $[-(n+1),n+1]$, and bounded between $0$ and $1$, to be a "continuous cut-off function"...

Comment: @paulgarrett: Yes, I was wondering what is going on? Everybody is telling me something is wrong with this answer. Somehow I couldn't see the error because I was reading what I wanted to read.

Comment: @timur, yes, a frequent problem in writing, that the writing itself is not literally the math, but only a narrative about someone's thinking. :)  And, unfortunately, sometimes the critics get into an unhelpful quasi-boolean attitude where a thing that is essentially correct and explains the essential idea is "literally/logically incorrect", if only perhaps due to typos. Very silly. But quite a few people who like "math" like a caricature of it, which is apparently about "absolute logical/literal correctness"... even though they themselves could not, in fact, follow up... nevermind...